# Understanding a fortran 77 code

Tags: fortran, goto, fortran77, implicit-declaration

What is the best way to take apart a fortran 77 code that uses implicit declarations and go to statements? I am used to working with f95 or higher with explicit declarations, modules, data types etc. This f77 stuff gives me headaches.

Any pointers from others experience on how to go about taking such ancient code apart would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: not sure what you are asking besides the obvious - put implicit none and let the compiler tell you need to declare. Upgrade all goto based constructs to modern form.  Could be a lot of work just for the satisfaction of it if its a large code that works.

Comment: I have never needed to use it, but I hear [SPAG](http://www.polyhedron.com/spag0html) is pretty good at converting F77 with `goto` into F90+ syntax.

Comment: Just draw a flowchart, pretend the boxes are linked by a piece of string, and pull it straight.  Then redraw the flowchart and you will have the logic.  Variables - if you can't remember I-N=integer and everything else is real, you've got a problem.  You could put in IMPLICIT NONE(A-Z): some F77 compilers accept that.  Then anything that hasn't been declared will cause an error.  This will give you a chance to add in the declarations.  Common blocks - list the contents of each block in alpha order.  Whenever you get a variable, look it up on the different cards.

Answer (score 1):

fortran77 code can be crufty. One useful thing to do is to modernize with some tools:

Alan Miller's to_f90 or Metcalf's "convert"

Polyhedron's "spag" tool to remove ~ two thirds of the goto's

Sometimes do/cycle/exit's are the only way to deal with fortran goto's
More about goto remediation can be found here:

http://engineering.dartmouth.edu/~d30574x/consulting/consulting_gotorefactor.html
http://engineering.dartmouth.edu/~d30574x/consulting/consultingIndex.html

Also, if you wanted it in matlab you can use f2matlab at the file exchange.

Good luck!